# How to detect if a Backbone model was deleted on the server?

Tags: backbone.js

What is the best way in Backbone.JS to determine if a model was deleted on the server in the meantime?

I need this for a simple webapp where multiple users can update or delete items, and, even if at the time the page was loaded a model did exist, by the time the other user is interacting with it it might have been already deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Include a revision number (or something similar) in your model, then on the server-side, when a client attempts to modify a resource you first verify that the revision number included matches what the server has. If it does, update the resource and then respond with the resource and the new revision number. If it doesn't, then respond with a [409 status code](http://httpstatus.es/409). If the client receives a 409 response, then it should pull the latest changes to the resource from the server and then attempt to push it's changes again with the updated revision number.